# jQuery: Affecting List Elements of the Same Depth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on creating a nested list that essentially walks users through a set of responses to arrive at an appropriate piece of information.

Something like this:

```
<ul id="questions">
    <li>I will be traveling in the summer.
        <ul class="sub hidden">
            <li>I will take a plane</li>
            <li>I will drive</li>
            <li>I will take a train</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>I will be traveling in the summer.
        <ul class="sub hidden">
            <li>I will take a plane.</li>
            <li>I will drive</li>
            <li>I will take a train</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Ideally, a user might arrive on this page, select "I will be travelling in summer". The second option would fade to grey and the nested sub options would appear. Then, if a user selected "I will drive", they may be presented with more sub-options, and the other two options would fade away.

I'm able to get the first tier of options to behave in the way I need them to. However, when a user clicks on an `li` element, I'm not sure how to get all non-selected `li` elements at the same depth and make them fade out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
     $("#questions li").click(function() {
         $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('fade');
         $(this).children().removeClass('hidden');
         $("ul#questions li").not('.selected').addClass('fade');
     });                            
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the **direct child** syntax:

```
$('#questions > li').not('.selected').addClass('fade');
```

or, more succinctly,

```
$('#questions > li:not(.selected)').addClass('fade');
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it selects the first level always. The question was *I'm not sure how to get all non-selected li elements at the same depth and make them fade out* and should be `$(this).siblings('li:not(.selected)').addClass('fade');`

Answer (score 0):

You would want to change `$("#questions li").click`

to directly select `li` children like this `$("#questions>li").click`

and for `$("ul#questions li").not('.selected')`

you would want something more like `.parent().children('li:not(.selected)')`

so that the current `li`, and it's siblings are affected.

**something similar to this**

```
$("#questions>li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected')//toggle selected
    .children().show().end()//show sub
    .parent().children('li:not(.selected)')//select !selected
    .children(':visible').hide();//hide !selected sub
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/9hNXG/